# Why is diamond structure the most stable structure?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Why is diamond structure the most stable structure? Is this mathematical issue or physics issue?

Doesn't this relate to quantum physics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most stable structure it will in fact decay to graphite (theoretically)

It is the hardest natural substance, which is due to the arrangement of it's atoms

Comment: You probably should explain _why_ the arrangement of atoms makes it stable in your answer :)